# Excel PowerQuery queries twice to download excel sheet 2 times on refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a relatively small M Query for Excel Power Queries in my excel workbook. It downloads an xls file with a post statement and puts the content into a worksheet:

```
let
    Token = "SomeTokenData", //for post
    myUrl = "https://www.example.com/theexporter.php?somesettings=xz",
    Quelle = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(myUrl, 
    [
        Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
        Content = Text.ToBinary(Token) 
            ]  
    ), null, false),
    MyExcelsheet = Quelle{[Item="Excelsheet",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    MyExcelsheet
```

So the "Load To" target of the query is a worksheet.
My problem is that if I look in fiddler what happens in the background I can see that the query gets executed twice on refresh. So it downloads the file twice.

I already turned off "allow data preview to download in the background" which made the query execute even 4 times.

After many trials this query was the smallest and downstripped query I could come up with downloading an excel sheet and loading it in a worksheet. But on every refresh, be it in the worksheet Refresh all or via vba Connection.Refresh results in 2 web requests.

Other settings on the query tested that did not change anything:
Allow background query false/true
Privacy settings are set to ignore